# How to limit just the incoming traffic rate using netem?

Tags: linux, bandwidth, bandwidth-throttling

How to limit the incoming bandwidth to say 1Mbps using netem? I have searched for tc commands but I could not understand whether the commands that were used limited both incoming and outgoing traffic.

In my case I just require my incoming bandwidth to be set at 1Mbps for 2 minutes and then at 2Mbps for next 2 minutes and so on without any delay or anything else on the packets.

I will be using google QUIC protocol instead of TCP.